# RSAT unavailable in Windows 10 - 1803

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-update

Since the October update of Windows 10 I'm not able to install RSAT. 
I have found numerus of guides telling me that this has been moved to feature on demand and I have tried installing following their instructions without success.

- Settings -> Apps -> Manage Optional Features -> Add a feature | **Feature not there**
- Update registry: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU and change the UseWUServer to 0 | **Nothing changed**
- PowerShell: Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online | **No result/No feature called like that**
- PowerShell: Add-WindowsCapability –online –Name “Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0” | **No feature like that.**
- GPEDIT: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Specific setting for optional component installation and component repair = Enabled and checked Download repair content | **still no RSAT feature**

[image]

None of above worked. So now im out of ideas.

According to Microsoft RSAT download page you should not download the RSAT tool the old way: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

> To install specific RSAT tools on Windows 10 October 2018 Update or
>   later
>
> Starting with Windows 10 October 2018 Update, RSAT is included as a
>   set of "Features on Demand" right from Windows 10. **Do not download an
>   RSAT package from this page**. Instead, just go to "Manage optional
>   features" in Settings and click "Add a feature" to see the list of
>   available RSAT tools. Select and install the specific RSAT tools you
>   need. To see installation progress, click the Back button to view
>   status on the "Manage optional features" page.
>
> See the list of RSAT tools available via Features on Demand. In
>   addition to installing via the graphical Settings app, you can also
>   install specific RSAT tools via command line or automation using DISM
>   /Add-Capability.
>
> One benefit of Features on Demand is that installed features persist
>   across Windows 10 version upgrades!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Starting with Windows 10 October 2018 Update, RSAT is included as a set of "Features on Demand" right from Windows 10. Do not download an RSAT package from this page.

October 2018 Update is 1809 not 1803.  1803 is the April 2018 Update.

> Winver actually showed that im on ver 1803 (OS Build 17134.122) and not 1809 as I thought.

You should install RSAT as outlined below.  You will have to wait until 1809 is released in order to install it on-demand.

> I have found numerous guides telling me that this has been moved to feature on demand and I have tried installing following their instructions without success.

Those guides do not apply to 1803.  You still need to install [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) before you can enable or disable RSAT tools.

**Until 1809 the installation process for RSAT has remained unchanged on Windows 10 and is identical across all supported versions and editions of Windows 10.**

> In the RSAT releases for Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows 8, tools
>   are again all enabled by default. You can open Turn Windows features
>   on or off to disable tools that you don't want to use. In RSAT for
>   Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows 8, you access GUI-based tools on
>   the Tools menu from within the Server Manager console.

Source:

- [Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) for Windows operating systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems)

Comment: Well something was installed a few days ago since it was pushed out to the computer and forced me to restart and after that i didnt have the RSAT tool anymore.

Comment: It wasn't the feature update.  You can always check the update history to confirm what was installed

Answer (score 0):

my company have a problem in the WSUS (the admin is planning to replace the server entirely with a new one in the next week)but this doesn't allow me to download the feature on demand.

The solution for me is to onstall on my windows 10 machine the RSAT package for the Windows server 2016.
This have worked, and at least for now i don't see any side effect :)

Go to the RSAT download link  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520
select your language and press the Download button
then download and execute 
WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu (or the x86 version for 32 bit machines...)